# font-face (icomoon) font not working IE

Tags: nginx, mime-types

Can anyone tell me, why my icomoon font is not working in IE 10/11 (edge is working properly)

https://www.fhstp.ac.at

This is my CSS

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'icomoon';
  src:url('../fonts/icomoon.eot?-dan3az');
  src:url('../fonts/icomoon.eot?#iefix-dan3az') format('embedded-opentype'),
      url('../fonts/icomoon.woff?-dan3az') format('woff'),
      url('../fonts/icomoon.ttf?-dan3az') format('truetype'),
      url('../fonts/icomoon.svg?-dan3az#icomoon') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

nginx Content-Type

```
application/x-font-woff
```

But in nginx mime.types stands following

```
application/font-woff woff;
```

Thank you for your help :-)

Comment: Does this only occur with the icomoon font? Or also with other fonts within IE? because if other external fonts are also not loaded then the problem might be in the specification of your mime types.

Comment: Yes, only with icomoon font. - Other fonts are from Google Fonts, these are working...

Comment: Do you have an HTML5 Shiv? I know there are a lot of Icomoon problems in IE because of how they are rendered.

Comment: modernizr.js with html5shiv

Comment: Actually I know that nginx is the bad guy.... but not why, since when... (on an other server with an older nginx it is working)